# What's the best way to prevent a browser from displaying images until they are fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I would like to set up a lean and mean image gallery, with thumbnails displayed inline. I'd like them not to windowshade in while loading, I'd like them to simply pop up or, if there's a way to detect their completion, use a jQuery effect like a quick `fadeIn()`.

I imagine a line of code like:

```
$(".thumb-image").whenLoaded(fadeIn(500));
```

But is there such an event? What's it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) event:

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // your code for images....
});
```

**Or Vanilla JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function(){
  // your code for images....
};
```

The `load` event fires after all images, DOM, external resources, frames, etc have loaded.

Comment: Thanks, sAc, I checked the jQuery reference and yes you can attach this to any selector. Neato.

Comment: Interestingly, there is a plugin that triggers the load event for cached images as well, in situations where the browser fails to do so...
http://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js